# How to get new time or date on every button click in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cakephp

When I enter multiple notes on button click Jquery date and time auto fill up in the textbox. Like this,

[image]

But when I click After two-minute date and time not change its display same as first selected.

Below the Code :

1. Jquery Date and Time Code:

   ```
   var nowDate = new Date(); 
   var mm = nowDate.getMonth() + 1; mm = (mm < 10) ? '0' + mm : mm;
   var dd = nowDate.getDate(); dd = (dd < 10) ? '0' + dd : dd;
   var new_today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + nowDate.getFullYear();

   var mi = nowDate.getMinutes(); mi = (mi < 10) ? '0' + mi : mi;
   var time = nowDate.getHours() + ":" + mi;
   ```
2. Dynamic HTML Code

   ```
    function addCallImage() {

     html  = '<tr id="call-row' + call_row + '" style="background-color: cadetblue;">';
     html += '  <td class="text-left col-md-6"><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="case_intake_call_record[' + call_row + '][caller_name]"  placeholder="Enter Call Record" class="form-control" value="" id="input-call' + call_row + '" ></textarea></td>';
     html += '  <td class="text-right col-md-3"><div class="input-group" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" data-date-end-date="0d"><input type="text" name="case_intake_call_record[' + call_row + '][caller_date]" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="form-control" value="'+new_today+'"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></div></td>';
     html += '  <td class="text-right col-md-3"><div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><input type="text" class="form-control" name="case_intake_call_record[' + call_row + '][caller_time]" value="'+time+'"></div></td>';
     html += '</tr>';
     $('#calls tbody').append(html);
     call_row++;
     clicks += 1;
     document.getElementById("autoCall").innerHTML = clicks;
     $("#autoCallhidden").val(clicks);  
     }
   ```
3. View File Code

   ```
       <tr>
           <td class="text-left" colspan="4"><button type="button" onclick="addCallImage();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>Click to Add Call Record</td>
       </tr>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the button click action occurs, you will want to make the function calls to nowDate. Try declaring the vars locally within the addCallImage() function so that they are reset every time the click occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use new Date inside your function.So when function called then new Date and time generated. 
This answer from Mobile so answer maybe not in welll format. :)

> var nowDate = new Date(); var mm = nowDate.getMonth() + 1; mm = (mm <
>   10) ? '0' + mm : mm; var dd = nowDate.getDate(); dd = (dd < 10) ? '0'
>   + dd : dd; var new_today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + nowDate.getFullYear(); var mi = nowDate.getMinutes(); mi = (mi < 10) ?
>   '0' + mi : mi; var time = nowDate.getHours() + ":" + mi;

Answer (score 0):

```js
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('li').on('click',function(e){
          $('li span').remove();
          var date = new Date();
          var date = date.toDateString();
          console.log(date);
          $(this).append( ' <span> ' + date + '</span>');
      });
  });
 </script>
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
      <h1>List</h1>
      <h2>Buy Fruits</h2>
      <ul>
        <li id="one"><em>fresh</em> Apple</li>
        <li id="two">Lemon</li>
        <li id="three">Orange</li>
        <li id="four">Grapes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Similarly you can use date.toTimeString() to get the time from Unix Timestamp.

To view this code in codepen visit:
https://codepen.io/saurav0083/pen/ZEbewVj

Comment: Hi saurav, please add description to your answer and explain better what is going on here. Thank you!